# Contar mayores de edad según fecha de nacimiento

Tags: mysql

Me pueden ayudar por favor:
Necesito saber cuantos mayores de edad hay en mi tabla usuarios, partiendo de la fecha de nacimiento.

Lo que he probado es con lo siguiente:

```php
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM $table WHERE FLOOR (f_nacimiento)/365 > 65
```

para tratar de encontrar a los mayores de 65 años

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! php o mysql? uno es un lenguaje de programacion, el otro una base de datos.. donde los queres contar?? y que intentaste hasta ahora???

Comment: @gbianchi, Gracias, he buscado respuesta mirado vídeos en youtube, y no he obtenido resultados. con lo que he probado es con lo siguiente:
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM $table WHERE FLOOR (f_nacimiento)/365 > 65
para tratar de encontar a los mayores de 65 años.

Comment: O sea.. la pregunta no tiene nada que ver con PHP... no sabemos como es la tabla, pero busca datediff para mysql y que la diferencia entre la fecha actual y la de nacimiento sea mayor a 65 y listo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ver documentación: Puedes usar [DATE_SUB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date_sub/).
Pongo de ejemplo el siguiente dataset:

```sql
INSERT INTO usuarios (id, nombre, f_nac) VALUES 
(NULL, 'Juan',  '2001-10-05'),
(NULL, 'Pedro', '1995-05-14'),
(NULL, 'Maria', '2014-02-11'),
(NULL, 'David', '2010-08-25'),
(NULL, 'Sara',  '2005-03-30');
```

Entonces, para encontrar a los mayores o iguales a, por ejemplo, 18 años:

```sql
SELECT * FROM usuarios 
WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 18 YEAR) >= f_nac;
```

El resultado, siendo la fecha actual `NOW() -> '2023-04-25'`:

```
1 Juan  2001-10-05
2 Pedro 1995-05-14
5 Sara  2005-03-30
```

Con eso le puedes hacer un `COUNT(*)` a esa misma consulta; obvio, con `65`.